# Docker-compose, revoke a secret from the running container

Tags: docker-compose, docker-secrets

For docker swarm mode, I found out that it can be easily done with `--secret-rm` option in `docker service update` command. But what is for docker-compose?

I tried to unmount /run/secrets in the running container via `docker exec` command and failed.